# mounting thermostat transformer in wall on old work box

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, transformer

I want to know if the following is reasonable and to code:

I want to install a wi-fi thermostat that requires 24v AC but the existing thermostat has no C-wire. So I want to install a 24V transformer to power the new thermostat.

The thermostat is in an interior wall. There is an existing outlet below the thermostat on the other side of a wooden stud.

I understand that these transformers are designed to be mounted outside an electrical box so that the 120V side is inside the box and the low-voltage side is outside.

My idea is to use a 2-gang old work box. I figure 2-gang so I can cut a hole in the wall big enough so the transformer will fit and to give me room to drill a hole through the stud to run wire if it can't get around the back of the stud.

I would mount the transformer to the side of the box (outside the box), run some romex from the existing outlet to the new box, and wire the 120V side of the transformer within the box. Run low-voltage wire from the transformer to the thermostat. Then angle the box with the transformer on its side into the hole, secure the box, and put a blank faceplate on the box. Using a deep box is an option to fit the transformer behind the drywall.

This means that the transformer would be within a hollow wall. It's an interior wall so there's no insulation or anything in the wall. The box would be near a stud so the transformer would be over a foot from the neighboring stud.

Is this a good idea?

Comment: There are devices to add a C wire to a thermostat if you have as few as two wires going to the thermostat.  Using one of these would be much cleaner to install.  Several companies make them as a "c-wire adder" or "[common maker](https://www.fast-stat.com/)".

Comment: It sounds like you are making this tougher than it needs to be.

Comment: It sounds like you are making this tougher than it needs to be. Unless you find a transformer listed for enclosure it will be out side the wall

Comment: The common maker is a cool solution but I actually have 6 zone valves and I'm looking to install multiple thermostats. The transformer in the control panel is 70VA. The zone valves are Honeywell and it looks like they're .32A each, which is a total of 46VA. I cannot find a power spec for the thermostats (they're also Honeywell coincidentally) and they're on all the time, so I'm not confident that there's enough juice to run them all. I would also have to install 5 receiver modules somewhere, and there's not a lot of space, although that's more an inconvenience.

Comment: I'm not aware of transformers being "listed for enclosure".  A google search really didn't bring up much. The point here is that the transformer is inside a hollow wall, not outside the wall. A Honeywell transformer (which is more confidence inducing than no-names on Amazon) says it has an operating temp of 130F, which seems pretty good, but I really don't know.

Comment: Keep in mind that it seems that most >40VA HVAC/Class 2 transformers have a fuse or breaker on them instead of being inherently current limited the way their smaller brethren are...what make and model are your zone valves BTW?

Comment: Paralleled dc outputs is usually fine but you may find parallel ac outputs the transformers get really hot, (some switching dc supplies don’t play well together). It is best to get the proper size or larger and not try to parallel AC transformers.

Comment: The transformers with circuit breakers are definitely a path to explore! Although they're quite heavy (3lb) to be hanging off an old work box that is clamped to the drywall... Will do some more research. The zone valves are Honeywell V8043E, although we may be replacing the boiler in the next year or two, and replace the zones with individual circulators